# C++ Vector of pointers, add referenced variable

Tags: c++

I have a vector of pointers to an object:

```
vector<Foo*> bar;
```

In a method, I am given an Foo object and need to add it to the vector. This is my current attempt:

```
void push(const Foo &a){
bar.insert(bar.begin(), a);
}
```

I know this doesnt work because `a` was passed as a reference, but I can't seem to get the pointer for `a` to add to `bar`.

How can I add `a` to the vector `bar`?

Comment: I don't understand the reason why you pass in a reference `const Foo &a`, why don't just pass in the pointer `void push(Foo *a)`

Comment: I was having weird results using the actual Foo objects

Comment: In that case, the answers down here should help

Comment: It would be a bad idea to merely pass the `Foo` by value, because you would then be adding the address of a local `Foo` object that is destroyed/dellocated when the function leaves.

Comment: @chris `Foo` just contains two private strings and a private int. I was given the header for the method, and have to fill the rest in

Comment: @Flynn, Yes, I realized from the other comment that it was probably trying to store the copy that did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an object in a container of pointers.

If you want to put an object in, then you'll need a container of objects:

```
vector<Foo> bar;
```

In that case, all the objects must be of the same type; if `Foo` is actually a base class, and you want to store a variety of different derived types, then you'll need to store pointers.

If you want a container of pointers, then you'll need to put a pointer in it:

```
bar.insert(bar.begin(), &a);
```

In that case, you need to take care with the object's lifetime, and make sure you don't use the pointer after the object is destroyed. [Smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add the address of `a`. Pointers store addresses, which is how they point to something.

```
bar.insert(bar.begin(), &a);
```

I'm presuming you have a good reason for using pointers, but make sure the `a` being passed in isn't temporary and that the object you pass in outlives the vector so that you don't end up with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but `a` is not a pointer in that code, even though it is passed by reference. You should be able to use & on it to gets it's address, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just take the address of `a`. The reference really is just that, a reference, so taking the address of it actually yields the address of what it refers to.

```
void push(const Foo& a)
{
    bar.insert(bar.begin(), &(a));
}
```